# Где в joomla 2 искать файлы подключенные через position()?

Tags: php, joomla

Например такая строка

```
<?php echo $view->position('header', 'mgll-nostyle'); ?>
```

Где искать этот файл?

Comment: а где этот код у вас находится ? в шаблоне ?

Comment: в шаблоне в файле Index.php

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понятно вы используете готовый шаблон, при этом отдельные фрагменты `VIEW` должны находится в `templates/you_template/layout` или `templates/you_template/block`.

Comment: ваще нет таких папок block или layout

Comment: А случайно на вашей Joomla не установлен дополнительный движок ? как например T3 ? возможно данное VIEW подключается из компонента или же, например, с дополнительного движка

Comment: это я не знаю, ибо проект у меня на фрилансе а я в jooml`е не шарю абсолютно